# Prevent `Plus` from reordering terms by default?

Tags: expression-manipulation

Writing `Plus[a,b]//FullForm` gives back `Plus[a,b]`, while `Plus[b,a]//FullForm` again returns `Plus[a,b]`. This means that the function `Plus` is secretly ordering its arguments. Is there a way to edit the properties of `Plus` and make it keep the order that I specify?

Comment: That's the `Orderless` attribute at work; without it, no way to see that `a + b` and `b + a` are the same thing.

Comment: For what purpose do you want to do this? There's always `HoldForm[b + a]`, `plus[b, a]`, formatting options, etc., but the correct solution I think requires knowledge of what it will be used for.

Comment: `Unprotect[Plus]; ClearAttributes[Plus, Orderless];` or `Inactivate[b + a]`

Comment: @J.M.isback. Ok, then maybe I can switch `Orderless` on and off depending on what steps I am computing? Ideally I would like to have it off by default and substitute it in like `/.Orderless->on` whenever I want to evaluate.

Comment: @march I want to implement specific ordering of monomials in polynomials in this way, for Groebner basis computation.

Comment: Tampering with the attributes of arithmetic functions is a bad idea. Why not use something inert, like `CirclePlus[]`?

Comment: @Kagaratsch check out DegreeLexicographic, etc.

Comment: @RolfMertig Is there also a command to reactivate `Orderless` for a single evaluation?

Comment: `SetAttributes[Plus, Orderless]` , but really: Don't do this. Use Inactivate.

Comment: Thanks for all the different suggestions! I will try each of them and see what works best.